# Compare values between 2 dataframes and transform data

Tags: python, regex, pandas, csv, formatting

The main aim of this script is to compare the regex format of the data present in the csv with the official ZIP Code regex format for that country, and if the format does not match, the script would carry out transformations on said data and output it all in one final dataframe.

I have 2 csv files, one (countries.csv) containing the following columns & data examples

INPUT:

| Contact ID | Country | Zip Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | 71293 |
| 2 | Italy | IT 2310219 |

and another csv (Regex.csv) with the following data examples:

| Country | Regex format |
| --- | --- |
| USA | [0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})? |
| Italy | \d{5} |

Now, the first csv has some 35k records so I would like to create a function which loops through the regex.csv (Dataframe) to grab the country column and also the regex format. Then it would loop through the country list to grab every instance where regex['country'] == countries['country'] and it would apply the regex transformation to the ZIP Codes for that country.

So far I have this function but I can't get it to work.

```
def REGI (dframe):
    dframe=pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(contacts)
    cols = list(contacts.columns)
    
    for index,row in mergeOne.iterrows():
        country = (row['Country'])
        reg = (row[r'regex'])
        
        for i, r in contactsS.iterrows():
            if (r['Country of Residence'] == country or r['Country of Residence.1'] == country or r['Mailing Country (text only)'] == country or r['Other Country (text only)'] == country) :
                dframe.loc[i] = r
                
        dframe['Mailing Zip/Postal Code']=dframe['Mailing Zip/Postal Code'].apply(str).str.extractall(reg).unstack().apply(lambda x:','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
    contacts.loc[contacts['Contact ID'].isin(dframe['Contact ID']),cols] = dframe[cols]
    dframe = dframe.dropna(how='all')
    
    return dframe
```

['Contact ID'] is being used as an identifier column.

The second for loop works on its own however I would need to manually re-type a new dataframe name, regex format and country name (without the first for loop).

At the moment I am getting the following error:
[ValueError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T57hx.png)
**ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups**

---

removed some columns to mimic example given above
[dataframes & error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF8v9.png)
[error continued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR5aV.png)

If I paste the results into a new dataframe, it returns the following:
[results in a new dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDwqA.png)

---

Example as text

| Account ID | Country | Zip/Postal Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | United Kingdom | WV9 5BT |
| 2 | Ireland | D24 EO29 |
| 3 | Latvia | 1009 |
| 4 | United Kingdom | EN6 1JE |
| 5 | Italy | 22010 |

REGEX table

| Country | Regex |
| --- | --- |
| United Kingdom | ([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2}) | (([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2}) | ([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) [0-9][A-Za-z]{2}) |
| Latvia | [L]{1}[V]{1}-{4} |
| Ireland | STRNG_LTN_EXT_255 |
| Italy | \d{5} |

United Kingdom regex:

([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) [0-9][A-Za-z]{2})

Comment: What is the objective here? Making sure the zip code matches the template per country? For instance Italy wouldn't match because of the leading "IT "?

Comment: @mozway the objective is to find wherever the ZIP/Postal code is not in the correct regex format, if it is not in the correct format, then the script would change that row's ZIP/Postal code to match the correct format. If it's already in the correct format, it would leave it as it is.

Comment: @mozway I have tried your solution however I am getting this error ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 10, placement implies 1

Comment: Please give the full dataset. It is working fine with the example.

Comment: @mozway one of the datasets just has the Country list and Regex formats (2 columns) and the other dataset has the contact info (Name, ID, Address 1,2,3, Country and Zip Code etc) (11 columns).

Comment: Please edit the question to provide an example that can be copied and which gives you an issue. I won't know how to solve your problem until I can actually see the error…

Comment: @mozway edited now with image links

Comment: Well, first "STRNG_LTN_EXT_255" is **not** a regex. Also, please provide the example as text that can easily be copied, not images

Comment: @mozway edited to include data in table. STRNG_LTN_EXT_255 is to show that the ZIP/Post can be any string of up to size 255. Am new to Regex, what should this be changed to?

Comment: You can use `'^.{,255}$'` (start of string, anything up to 255 times, end of string). Your table has issues with formatting wrap your text in  between "```" (see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help )

Comment: @mozway the UK regex is too large to put in a table I think, I've pasted it underneath the Regex table

Answer (score 1):

Based on your response to my comment, I would suggest to directly fix the zip code using your regexes:

```
df3 = df2.set_index('Country')

df1['corrected_Zip'] = (df1.groupby('Country')
                           ['Zip Code']
                           .apply(lambda x: x.str.extract('(%s)' % df3.loc[x.name, 'Regex format']))
                        )
df1
```

This groups by country, applies the regex for this country, and extract the value.

output:

```
   Contact ID Country    Zip Code corrected_Zip
0           1     USA       71293         71293
1           2   Italy  IT 2310219         23102
```

*NB. if you want you can directly overwrite `Zip Code` by doing `df1['Zip Code'] = …`*

*NB2. This will work only if all countries have an entry in `df2`, if this is not the case, you need to add a check for that (let me know)*

NB3. if you want to know which rows had an invalid zip, you can fetch them using:

```
df1[df1['Zip Code']!=df1['corrected_Zip']]
```